# Unable to log in to WordPress site from Plesk Obsidian due to Undefined Function errors

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk

Okay, so I'm having a big issue with my WordPress site using Phlox Pro theme.
I have re-installed this theme so many times and I am really struggling to work out what is going wrong here.
From the error PHP results below (commented out to hide my domain), can anyone please advise / help me out with what this all means?

---

Error getting administrator credentials: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function auxin_is_true() in /var/www/vhosts/******.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/auxin-elements/includes/compatibility/wp-rocket/wp-rocket.php:14

Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/vhosts/******.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): auxels_check_wp_rocket_minify_option()

#1 /var/www/vhosts/******.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()

#2 /var/www/vhosts/******.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()

#3 /var/www/vhosts/******.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-settings.php(623): do_action()

#4 /opt/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-

---

I'm getting the notion that WP Rocket plugin doesn't play well here?

I've tried the following to stop this unexpected behaviour from happening;

1. Reinstalled WordPress from clean copy
2. Switched to stock theme
3. Ran this theme without WP Rocket installed
4. FTP deleted AdvancedCache.php and emptied Cache folder in /wp-content/

I log in to this WordPress site from Plesk and although I get the new tab with "Retrieving WordPress credentials..." and this looks hopeful, the window cancels itself out then reverts back to the Plesk dashboard. :(

Any help right now would be greatly appreciated :)

I have already explained this in the main post.

Comment: So even without having WP Rocket installed, you still see references to it in the stack trace?